# How to write log messages from arcpy to ArcGis server?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing-service

Published geoprocessing services write logs that are available at ArcGis Server Manager (`arcgis-server/arcgis/manager/log.html`)

Arcpy has `AddMessage`, `AddError`, etc methods for logging, but they are doesn't works when script is published as geoprocessing service. As I understand, they works only locally in ArcMap.

Is there some way to write server logs from arcpy?

Comment: you need to turn the message level on the service itself to INFO | WARNING | ERROR to show applicable arcpy.Add__messages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the `arcpy.AddMessage(message)`, it should show up in your published GP, but it shows up on the job messages page (not the server logs as you indicated in your question). You also need to enable this in the service properties (or when you publish the service):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `AddMessage` will add a message to the geoprocessing job message queue:
[image]

`jobs/ja861064b634648f1be2371e2307c6112?f=json`

For general logging, I use python logging:
`import logging`
and make sure the formatter has a process id:
`formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s p%(process)s {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s |-| %(message)s')`

```
# Set up logging

logfilepath = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(),'example.log')

logger = logging.getLogger('example_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.handlers = []

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s p%(process)s {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s |-| %(message)s')
fh = logging.FileHandler(logfilepath)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

logger.info('example script start...')

fh.flush()

logger.debug('Importing ArcPy...')
import arcpy
logger.debug('Importing ArcPy Import Complete')
```