# Printing error message to console or log file in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, error-999999

My code is as follows:

Essentially, I have one table in my database that is not able to convert into my FGDB. When I run on command line,  I am able to get an error message of:

> WARNING: Failed to convert Database Connections\DB.sde\Tablexxx. ERROR
>   999999: Error executing function.
>
> Failed to execute (CopyRows).

But i am not able to print/write this error message to console (via print statement) or to a log file (via log.write). It seems that in my code, the except statements are not even being reached, even though an error is occuring?

Comment: Your indentation for the second and third lines of code that you have presented is astray. I think you should print(tables) as a new first line.  You have a tag for file geodatabase but seem to be using an enterprise geodatabase.

Comment: `arcpy.AddError` only functions with an ArcGIS script tool or Python toolbox tool. Is this a stand-alone script?

Comment: `print` does not work within the ArcGIS platform. You want `arcpy.AddMessage` or its siblings, `arcpy.AddWarning`, `arcpy.AddError`.  Just for grins, the `messages` object in Python toolbox uses `messages.addMessage` (lowercase `a` in `add`) and `messages.addWarningMessage` and `messages.addErrorMessage` (gotta stay on your toes)

Comment: This, https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/160436/28687, may help. This is about piping your stream to be handled by right medium, I think.

Comment: I’m not clear why you’ve deleted your code from this coding question. What precisely did you run from the “command line” and by that do you mean the Python window of ArcMap or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use `except Exception as e:`

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> try:
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis ("fdgfd", "dfgdg", "dsfsdfsd")
except Exception as e:
    print e


Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset fdgfd does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (Buffer).

>>>
```

Comment: I tried this as well but the error message still does not show up

Answer (score 1):

You are using `print` in one statement and `arcpy.AddError()` in another.  The command line won't print errors from `AddError()` and the ArcGIS console won't print from `print`.

To be able to print the error both within the ArcGIS console and the command line you may want to use *both* `print` and `AddError()` from within your `except` statements:

```
except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    arcpy.AddError(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
    print(arcpy.GetMessages(2))

except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[1]
    arcpy.AddError(e.args[0])
    print(e.args[0])
```